# Array value changing

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have 2 arrays - `activeDealers` and `normalDealers`.

```js
let normalDealers = [
   { nickname: 'one', inactive: false, dealer: true },
   { nickname: 'two', inactive: false, dealer: false },
   { nickname: 'three', inactive: false, dealer: false }
]

activeDealers = [...normalDealers]
```

then the `normalDealers` array should pass through some conditions like this

```js
if (normalDealers.length > 1) {
    const prev = normalDealers.shift();
    normalDealers.push(prev);
}
```

After this, the `normalDealers` array will be like this:

```
[
    { nickname: 'two', inactive: false, dealer: false },
    { nickname: 'three', inactive: false, dealer: false },
    { nickname: 'one', inactive: false, dealer: true }
]
```

I want to change the `normalDealers` array's 0-th index obj value to
`- { nickname: 'two', inactive: false, dealer: true }`

```js
[
    { nickname: 'two', inactive: false, dealer: true },
    { nickname: 'three', inactive: false, dealer: false },
    { nickname: 'one', inactive: false, dealer: false }
]
```

But I want the original order of the array inside the `activeDealers` with updated dealer status value.

Expecting output:

```js
[
    { nickname: 'one', inactive: false, dealer: false },
    { nickname: 'two', inactive: false, dealer: true },
    { nickname: 'three', inactive: false, dealer: false }
]
```

Comment: Why do you need to change the original order at all? Why are you using `shift`? Why can't you use a `for loop` and mutate the object at a particular index?

Comment: @ArjisChakraborty Can you give an answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```js
const activeDealers = [
    { nickname: 'one', inactive: false, dealer: true },
    { nickname: 'two', inactive: false, dealer: false },
    { nickname: 'three', inactive: false, dealer: false }
];

const normalDealers = [
    { nickname: 'two', inactive: false, dealer: true },
    { nickname: 'three', inactive: false, dealer: false },
    { nickname: 'one', inactive: false, dealer: false }
];

activeDealers.forEach((entryA, indexA) => {
    normalDealers.forEach((entryB, indexB) => {
        if (entryA.nickname === entryB.nickname) {
            activeDealers[indexA] = normalDealers[indexB];
        }
    });
});

console.log(activeDealers);
```

It just replaces the entry with the corresponding `nickname` in `activeDealers` with the entry in `normalDealers`, assuming that each `nickname` occurs only once. I'm not sure if that's the best way to achieve what you're aiming for, though. To determine that, you would have to describe what the meaning behind it is. Why are two arrays needed at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `unshift` method.
The `unshift` method inserts new elements at the beginning of an array,
and the `pop` method adds new elements to the end of the array, both return the new length of the array.

```
if (normalDealers.length > 1) {
    const prev = normalDealers.shift();
    normalDealers.unshift(prev);
}
```